# Why are redux-offline effects executed synchronously?

Tags: redux, react-redux, offline

Seems like redux-offline effects are executed synchronously, taken one at a time off the outbox and executed till completed. Only when completed, the next one is executed.

This makes sense if you are not sure there's a connection: you probably don't want to execute (maybe dozens/hundreds of) calls that are waiting in the outbox and may fail. However, it means that once there **is** a connection, you slow your application by creating a bottle-neck for your effects (which are usually HTTP calls).

Is the above analysis correct? Is there a way to make the outbox execute effects in parallel?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read [ask] and help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason they are executed synchronously is because order sometimes matters. Mainly when you are making multiple requests against the same resource.

So if a user updates the same resource twice, and the first update were executed after the second by Redux Offline, some of the second update could get overwritten.

There is no way to execute effects in parallel.

Comment: Not exactly true - parallel effects can be achieved by overriding the `queue.enqueue` function in offlineConfig and making that immediately execute the action instead of appending it to the queue. Note that you'll of course need to manually dispatch the commit and rollback actions when doing it this way. I usually make all "GET" actions this way, because usually their order doesn't matter.